# Can Uchihas get Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan by exchanging their eyes?

Tags: naruto

Let's say Uchiha A and an Uchiha B both have awakened their Mangekyou Sharingan. If A and B exchange their eyes, can they unlock Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan?

Comment: No, if that was possible, Madara & Itachi have done that with there brothers.

Answer (score 5):

In the Manga, only:

- Uchiha Madara,
- Uchiha Izuna (Madara's brother),
- Uchiha Shinsui,
- Uchiha Itachi(Sasuke's brother),
- Uchiha Sasuke,
- Uchiha Fugaku(Itachi's and Sasuke's father)
- Uchiha Obito,

Is shown to have awakened Mangekyou Sharingan (henceforth the MS). Of those 7 only 2 is confirmed to have an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan (henceforth the EMS), that is Uchiha Madara and Uchiha Sasuke.

**Uchiha Madara**

Madara gained his EMS after taking his brother's MS. Note that he claimed that his brother gave it to him. Madara did not take it from him by force. When Madara told this story, his brother was shown to be on his deathbed. By the time Madara gained his EMS, his original eyes has lost its light, he is practically blind.

**Uchiha Sasuke**

Sasuke gained his EMS from Uchiha Itachi. At first he hesitated in transplanting Itachi's eyes into his. After his eyes got worse from the extensive use of MS techniques, he agreed to the transplantation and thus gained his EMS. Itachi's eyes were also near blind.

There are 4 points that is similar between the two.

- **One** is that they have their original eyes evolved into MS.
- **Two**, they transplanted the other eyes from their brother.
- **Three** they transplanted their brother's eyes when their original eyes are blind or near blind.
- **Four** both's brothers are dead when they transplanted the eyes.

IIRC it was told in the manga that transplantation is better done between close relative since they are more compatible.

If, only the first two conditions are necessary for the EMS then yes, any close relative that has awakened MS can simply exchange eyes for both to awaken EMS. If point 3 is also need to be met then they still can exchange eyes after exhausting their eyes, making it near blind. If point 4 is also necessary then they can't simply exchange eyes as one needs to die before the other can transplant their eyes and awaken EMS.

Comment: This of course all assumes the Transplant eyes do not Fuse together with the originals, which apparently is some kind of theory on the topic. Death realistically should not matter at all, but this is anime after all, so who knows. It was just left too open for interpretation as of right now, though if it was realistic, then it would be swapping eyes and it would work for both of them.

Comment: I agree that the eyes should not fuse. I disagree that death should not matter, considering that Mangekyou Sharingan itself was awakened upon death of someone important.

Comment: case 1 and 2 are very important but, brother is not must but must be strong blood ties. case 3 and 4 are not necessary.

Comment: You forgot Uchiha Fugaku on the list of Mangekyou Sharingan users.

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate the EMS you would need the eyes of a relative who has activated MS the prime example of this is Obito he transferred plenty of other sharingans into his missing eye socket as there was more than just him and Itachi with MS during the time of the Uchiha Massacre (where he took the eyes of uchiha that have activated at least a regular sharingan) so its safe to safe hes at least transplanted one other eye with MS in that eye socket but has never awakend EMS.

Answer (score 0):

Two additional points to consider as per why theyre not fused:

1. What Madara said and did during the 4th war
2. The uchiha rip off shin uchiha
3. Madara said to Sasuke "maybe I should take your eyes before i get my rinnegan back" just after his full revival. And what he did to Kakashi just before being sliced in half by Sasuke was taking his (Obito's right eye) and planted it into his socket. The instinct of putting the donor eye into his eye socket probably means that the eyes dont fuse (Madara already as EMS which is why Obito's stay they same in Madara's eye socket). This also assumes the donor is still alive (Madara did say killing sasuke would be a waste of those eyes implying sasuke would resist)
4. Shin's body is tattered with sharingans implying no matter where you put em, the sharingan will work. Why this is important is because his "children" also have the same pattern implying those who have the exact same dna would awaken the same MS with the same power. When the body is introduced to a pair of eyes from somebody else it would react differently, my guess is; if the reciever had MS, they could potentially awaken EMS when the donor MS is transplanted into them regardless of blood relation. The blood relation mightve been a theory in the manga, an assumption, misused information.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.